# Fixed left and top panel - all other pages must load in inner portion without using iframe

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, forms, jsp

Everyone,

I am implementing one project and facing below metnioned challenge -

When user logged in - top and left panel will be fixed with multiple links for multiple application. See image below

[image]

My requirement is, when i click on multiple option, only inner part should get refreshed with specified page.

If I click on submit button, then also my left and top panel will not get refreshed.

In short if i perform any activity or submit event only inner portion should get submitted.

I want to implement this without using iframe, as iframe is not secure.

I read regarding implementing using Ajax. But I am not able to understand how every action on multiple page will get submitted and only inner page will get refresh or next page get loaded.

Any kind of help is welcome.

Comment: Besides `ajax`,`sitemesh` is also a good choice for you,it's used to decorator pages.

Comment: @lucumt not only design, I want to redirect and submit forms without refreshing top and left panel. I am having more than 25 modules, all are having links on left panel, then on click of links, module will get loaded into inner portion of page. Any Query please ask.